# How to define a simple dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a simple dataset i.e.(1.22 -0.86 -1.35 -1.46 0.67 2.77 -0.50 0.34 -0.57 -0.05).

 I would like to define this as a data set in R so I don't have to manually calculate the mean and variance and possibly plot this. How do I do this?

I have tried `data<-[1.22 -0.86 -1.35 -1.46 0.67 2.77 -0.50 0.34 -0.57 -0.05]` but I get `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "data<-1.22 -0.86 -1.35 -1.46 0.67"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
data <- c(1.22,-0.86,-1.35,-1.46,0.67,2.77,-0.50,0.34,-0.57,-0.05)
mean(data)
var(data)
plot(data)
plot(sort(data))
hist(data)
```

May I recommend http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf ?

Answer (score 4):

You could also put the numbers in a file, separated by spaces or new lines, and use 'scan':

```
data = scan("data.txt")
mean(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'c' function combines values into a list.

```
data<-c(1.22, -0.86 etc)
```

then

```
mean(data)
sd(data)
plot(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous responsese, if you use the scan function without setting any argument then it will expect the data to be entered from the command line with individual elements seperated by whitespace (spaces and newlines).  An empty entry (pressing enter twice) will end the imput.

For a quick little dataset working at the command line this can be a quick and easy method to enter the data.